# SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation (db_insert Function)

Tags: database

I try to build new module in drupal 7
I try to insert some data in some where inside the code 
it was working in many functions 
but suddenly when I try to do the following

```
  db_insert('payment_request')
    ->fields(array(
      'payment_item' => $data['payment_item'],
      'change' => $data['change'],
      'via' => $data['via'],
      'userlist' => serialize($userlisthidden),
      'startdate' => strtotime($data['startdate']),
      'enddate' => strtotime($data['enddate']),  
      'hash' => $hash   
    ))->execute();
```

it gives me an error

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'change, via, userlist, startdate, enddate, hash) VALUES ('2', '1', '1', 'a:1:{i:' at line 1
```

I checked the table and the fields and the values 
every thing are correct

so I decide to insert static data like the following :

```
  db_insert('payment_request')
    ->fields(array(
      'payment_item' => 'qq',
      'change' => 'qq',
      'via' => 'qq',
      'userlist' => 'qq',
      'startdate' => 'qq',
      'enddate' => 'qq',  
      'hash' => 'qq'   
    ))->execute();
```

But it gives me the same error 
so, what i miss here, please help me

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`CHANGE` is a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html) in MySQL. PDO doesn't have a built-in function for quoting identifiers (just string literals and dates), so presumably Drupal simply hasn't tried to implement this on PDO's behalf.

Using a different column name would be the simplest solution.

Answer (score 3):

[Reserved Word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html) are permitted as identifiers if you quote them.

For example:

instead of using keyword `interval` like this:

```
CREATE TABLE interval (begin INT, end INT);
```

You could try

```
CREATE TABLE `interval` (begin INT, end INT);
```

Comment: That's certainly true, but the docs do explicitly state only to use `db_insert()` for insert queries (not `db_query()`). So yes, it can be done, but you might find it breaks portability to another DBMS. Obviously this may or may not be a problem depending on requirements, but it might not be suitable for, e.g., a contrib module